# Clear case license issue

Tags: clearcase, flexlm

We are using ClearCase for SCM.

We installed ClearCase 7.1.1 version. We are using the atria license.
Now we are moving to the flexm license. Every operation is working fine in the server.

But in the client machine log, I am getting this error.

```
Error: License checkout error from Rational Common Licensing:
The FEATURE name MultiSite with version 1.0 cannot be found
License server system does not support this feature.
Feature:       MultiSite
License path:  27000@inhyvwccserver1;
FLEXnet Licensing error:-18,147
For further information, refer to the FLEXnet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".
```

How to troubleshoot this strange error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible (as mentioned in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014817971)) to see that error when:

- the client is aware of at least one multisite vob (cleartool lsvob would list one vob as replicated)
- your FlexLm license server doesn't include a multisite license.